# Cloud Run: Forbidden error while accesing service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I have created a `Wordpress` Service using `Cloud Run` . I deployed using below command

```
        gcloud beta run deploy wp --image gcr.io/<project>/wp:v1 \
        --add-cloudsql-instances <project>:us-central1:mysql2  \
        --update-env-vars DB_HOST='127.0.0.1',DB_NAME=mysql2,DB_USER=wordpress,DB_PASSWORD=password,CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE='<project>:us-central1:mysql2'
```

The service is deployed fine but while trying to access the service it is showing below error

```
 <h1>Error: Forbidden</h1>
<h2>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/</code> from this server.</h2>
```

UPDATES:

`Dockerfile` is as follows . I am following this...
https://github.com/acadevmy/cloud-run-wordpress

```
 FROM wordpress:5.2.1-php7.3-apache
 EXPOSE 80
 # Use the PORT environment variable in Apache configuration files.
 RUN sed -i 's/80/${PORT}/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/ports.conf
 # wordpress conf
 COPY wordpress/wp-config.php /var/www/html/wp-config.php

 # download and install cloud_sql_proxy
 RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install net-tools wget && \
 wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O /usr/local/bin/cloud_sql_proxy && \ 
 chmod +x /usr/local/bin/cloud_sql_proxy


 COPY wordpress/cloud-run-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

 ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
 CMD ["/usr/local/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND"]
```

##docker-entrypoint.sh

```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  # Start the sql proxy
  cloud_sql_proxy -instances=$CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE=tcp:3306 &

   # Execute the rest of your ENTRYPOINT and CMD as expected.
```

Following can be seen in Console Log

[image: Cloud Run Log]

We allowed Unauthenticated authentication and now the error is

"**Error establishing a database connection**"

**Additional Updates:**

The DB is running with a `private IP` so using `Serverless VPC` .

DB information is as follows:

```
     gcloud sql instances list
     NAME    DATABASE_VERSION  LOCATION       TIER         PRIMARY_ADDRESS  PRIVATE_ADDRESS  STATUS
     mysql2  MYSQL_5_7         us-central1-b  db-f1-micro  -                10.0.100.5       RUNNABLE
```

This is `Serverless VPC` access range

```
 testserverlessvpc  kube-shared-vpc us-central1     192.168.60.0/28     200     300
```

Now I have added an additional parameter as shown below with both `gcloud run deploy and gcloud run service` command

--vpc-connector projects/< HOST-Project >/locations/us-central1/connectors/testserverlessvpc

But during `gcloud run deploy` it is failing with below error

```
    ⠏ Deploying new service... Internal system error, system will retry.
```

Comment: 1) What is the URL? 2) Is your container and WordPress already setup before deploying? 3) Unless you are deploying an already configured instance of WordPress in your container, you will not be able to configure WordPress. Cloud Run does not have persistent storage.

Comment: The entrypoint to your container is not hitting the proper path. Check your Dockerfile and basepath of the web service.

Comment: your DB host is strange. There is no DB host, it's a Linux socket which is open to interact with the database. Is it this URL which is unknown?

Comment: Added the Dockerfile in description....

Comment: You need to add more detailed error to get answers. Clearly there's a database connection error. Please read https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run.

Comment: Were you able to get this working or are you still getting an error message?

Comment: No luck yet . The DB is running with a private IP from a shared VPC . Updated description with more information..

Comment: The "Internal server error" is resolved after fixing the IAM permission needed for SharedVPC . Below is the corresponding note from Documentation. ""The host project administrator must grant the following accounts the Serverless VPC Access User IAM role on the host project,""